# Notification won't show up when the app closed

Tags: python, android, notifications, kivy

I have a problem with my application, if i close the application the notification won't show up, but if i stay in the application the notification will show up. How to fix this problem (sorry my English is bad)

```
class InsertDataWid(BoxLayout):
def __init__(self,mainwid,**kwargs):
    super(InsertDataWid,self).__init__()
    self.mainwid = mainwid

def insert_data(self):
    con = sqlite3.connect(self.mainwid.DB_PATH)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    now = datetime.now()
    d1 = self.ids.ti_ktp.text
    d2 = self.ids.ti_phone.text
    d3 = self.ids.ti_name.text
    d4 = self.ids.ti_site.text
    d5 = now.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S')
    a1 = (d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)
    s1 = 'INSERT INTO PeminjamanKunci(Ktp, Phone, Name, Site, Date)'
    s2 = 'VALUES("%s",%s,"%s","%s","%s")' % a1
    try:
        cursor.execute(s1+' '+s2)
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        self.mainwid.goto_database()
        self.trigger_notify()
    except Exception as e:
        message = self.mainwid.Popup.ids.message
        self.mainwid.Popup.open()
        self.mainwid.Popup.title = "Database Error"
        if '' in a1:
            message.text = 'Please Fill The Data Correctly'
        else:
            message.text = str(e)
        con.close()

def back_to_dbw(self):
    self.mainwid.goto_database()

def notify(self,mode='normal'):
    title = self.ids.ti_name.text +" WKWKWKW"
    message = self.ids.ti_site.text + self.ids.ti_phone.text
    ticker = self.ids.ti_ktp.text
    if PY2:
        title = title.decode('utf8')
        message = message.decode('utf8')
    kwargs = {'title': title, 'message': message, 'ticker': ticker}
    notification.notify(**kwargs)

def trigger_notify(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.notify, 30)
```

Comment: on which device are you testing...

Comment: android 7.0 and above